# Create array from csv file and data is all in one field

Tags: python, arrays, csv, gis

My ultimate goal is to get my lat long from an already created csv file into an array to then create the polygon in a shp file.  I have 10 records that can create 10 polygons.  My problem that I dont know how to tackle is the manipulation of the csv file.  All the lat long coordinates associated with one polygon are in one field (cell). ie: my column name is "lat_long" and in it there are 15+ numbers in just a single field.  Every 2 numbers represents the lat long of a point of the polygon written like this: 2089,15663,2103,15664 etc..

My data looks like this now:

Sample  lat_long    check   prod

1   2071, 15600,  2089, 15663, 2103, 15664  wfc crush

2   2071, 15601, 2089, 15663, 2104,15660    qpf apple

3   1981, 15541, 2005, 15571, 2028, 15570   astro   tomato

I want it to look like this:

Sample  Lat Long    Check   prod

1   20.71   -156    wfc crush

1   20.89   -156.66 wfc crush

1   21.03   -156.64 wfc crush

2   20.71   -156.01 qpf apple

2   20.89   -156.63 qpf apple

2   21.03   -156.64 qpf apple

3   19.81   -155.41 astro   tomato

3   20.05   -155.71 astro   tomato

3   20.28   -155.7  astro   tomato

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your question in its current state is very unclear and it's difficult for people to help you. Try to post all the relevant parts - your csv, and the relation between your code and the csv, etc. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Comment: You can split the read in filed by `,` but looking at the data you have how do you know if a value is negative or positive? How was the csv file created? MIght be easier/more reliable to change that.

Comment: So `2089,15663` become `(20.89, -156.63)` I see where the `.`comes from. But the `-` minus ? How do you that `15663` is negative?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv


# Open a new csv to write to
with open("output.csv", "w", newline='') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)

    # Write the header row
    writer.writerow(['Sample', 'lat', 'long', 'check', 'prod'])

    # Open the source .csv file.  You'll need it
    # to be in the same directory as this script.
    with open("data.csv", newline='') as in_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(in_file)

        row_num = 0
        for row in csv_reader:
            # Skip the header row of the input data
            if row_num > 0:
                num_columns = len(row)

                sample = int(row[0])
                check = row[num_columns - 2]
                prod = row[num_columns - 1]

                # Loop through the columns by 2 columns at a time
                for col in range(1, num_columns - 2, 2):
                    # Get the raw lat long data
                    raw_lat = row[col]
                    raw_lng = row[col + 1]

                    # Split the lat into components and parse as a float
                    lat = float(raw_lat[0:-2] + '.' + raw_lat[-2:])

                    # Split the long into components and parse as a float
                    lng = float(raw_lng[0:-2] + '.' + raw_lng[-2:])

                    out_row = [sample, lat, lng, check, prod]
                    writer.writerow(out_row)

            row_num += 1
```